# How do I edit the index page of your domain in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url

So right now I have this in my .htaccess page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|fonts|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

which makes it so that I can access http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/page by going to http://www.yourdomain.com/page. However what I can't figure out is how to edit the page that shows up at http://www.yourdomain.com.

I've tried creating a controller called index, but this doesn't do anything unless you go to http://www.yourdomain.com/index

Can anyone help with this? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default controller that loads when there are no url segments is defined in
 `application/config/routes.php`:

From: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

> #### Reserved Routes
>
> `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`
>
> This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
>   URI contains no data, which will be the case when people load your
>   root URL. In the above example, the "welcome" class would be loaded.
>   You are encouraged to always have a default route otherwise a 404 page
>   will appear by default.

If there are no url segments besides the controller itself, by default the `index()` method of that controller is called (this is always the case, not just in regards to routing). So with this example you would look at the `welcome` controller and `index` method and see which view files etc. are being loaded.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed but for some reason I couldn't find it after much Googling! Yeah!!!